# NamedPipeServerStream Reader/Writer thread C#

Tags: c#, thread-safety, named-pipes

I’m attempting to share a NamedPipeServerStream instance between two threads, a reader and a writer. The program works but when I attempt to create two instances of the ServerProcess object the writer thread starts hanging. Where am I going wrong?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

The spawning method is as follows:

```
 public class ServerPrcoess
 {
    private static NamedPipeServerStream m_NamePipeHandle;
    public  static void StartPipe()
    {
        int i = 0;

        Thread[] OPCServerReader = new Thread();
        Thread[] OPCServerWriter = new Thread();

        m_NamePipeHandle = new NamedPipeServerStream(PIPENAME, PipeDirection.InOut, 254, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        m_NamePipeHandle.WaitForConnection();

        OPCServerReader = new Thread(PipeReaderThread);
        OPCServerReader.IsBackground = true;
        OPCServerReader.Start(i);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        OPCServerWriter = new Thread(PipeWriterThread);
        OPCServerWriter.IsBackground = true;
        OPCServerWriter.Start();
      }
 }
```

The reader thread is similar to below and creates a binary reader object using the pipe handle :-

```
private  static void PipeReaderThread(object ThreadNo)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Reader Thread Number: {0}", (int)ThreadNo);
     try
     {

         StreamOPCMessageReader oMsgReader = new StreamOPCMessageReader(m_NamePipeHandle);

            ...
```

And the writer thread does the equivalent using the same pipe handle.

```
private static void PipeWriterThread(object _ThreadNo)
{         
     int ThreadNo  = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
     try
     {               
        StreamOPCMessageWriter oMsgWriter = new StreamOPCMessageWriter(m_NamePipeHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not create multiple instances of NamedPipeServerStream with the same name(*PIPENAME*).

Comment: If you initialising each NamedPipeServerStream instance in it's own thread then I would I thought it wouldn't of been the issue

Comment: try to run `new Thread(() => {new NamedPipeServerStream("pipe"); Thread.Sleep(1000);}).Start();` twice